# bash loop to append some text to a file and send a mail

Tags: bash, email, while-loop

I am trying to write a bash "while loop" to take inputs from a INPUT FILE add that those to a MAIL TEMPLATE and send a mail to the user.

When i am trying this , the MAIL TEMPLATE is getting overwritten (for obvious reasons) and the second mail that the script sends for the second  has the details which script has appended for the first iteration.

How can i modify my script so that for every input , the script takes the details , add them to the MAIL TEMPLATE and sends a mail to the user, with the original MAIL TEMPLATE remain untouched.

heres my script

```
while read -r i
do
    cat >> MAILTEMPLATE.txt <<EOF
    #Some text that i need to append to the MAILTEMPLATE.txt file for the specific input
    EOF
    cat MAILTEMPLAT.txt|mail emp@org.com
done<inputfile
```

Comment: Don't append to the template file itself. `cat` the template and the addition to a new file that you then delete.

Comment: **No whitespace** in front of the terminating `EOF`

Comment: so #Reisner , do you think this is how it should be..

while read -r i
do
cp MAILTEMPLATE.txt newfile.txt
cat >> newfile.txt <<EOF
some text here
EOF
cat newfile.txt|mail emp@org.com
done<inputfile
rm newfile.txt

Comment: @EtanReisner *newfile.txt* in not needed, you could: `mail emp@org.com < <( cat template - << eof ... )`

Answer (score 1):

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could do this without requirement of temporary file:

### .1 using your syntax:

```
while read -r i
do
    cat MAILTEMPLATE.txt - <<-EOF | mail emp@org.com
        #Some text that i need to append to the MAILTEMPLATE.txt file for the specific input
        EOF
done <inputfile
```

### .2 Better by using function

```
buildMail() {
    cat MAILTEMPLATE.txt - <<-eof
        This is appended to mail body
        Where $1 is 1st arg of buildMail function
        $2 second and $@ is whole args list.
        eof
}

while read -r i ;do
    buildMail "$i" Other arg may be used... |
        mail emp@org.com
done< inputfile
```

Care to use *tabulations* only to indent your inline text. They will be ommited by `<<-eof` syntax.